# URLDownloadToFileW Sharepoint download URL with unicode characters in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, unicode, download

I have found that downloading a non-unicode Sharepoint Excel file from VBA using URLDownloadToFile works well. However, if the URL has unicode characters (Chinese) then I see that URLDownloadToFileW is required. However, I have not been able to get it to work. The URL is in the Excel Workbook.FullName.

ex.

```
ret = URLDownloadToFileW(0, ActiveWorkbook.FullName, sAttachFilename, 0, 0)
```

In this case, ret is non-0. I have tried:

```
ret = URLDownloadToFileW(0, StrConv(ActiveWorkbook.FullName,vbUnicode), sAttachFilename, 0, 0)
```

Same result.

Has anyone been able to download unicode URLs in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, the Excel workbook is already downloaded and open. Therefore, there is no need to download it again to a file (ex. directly from Sharepoint). For my requirements, simply executing an ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs method works for me.